# GNU make using target file name in prerequisite

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a list of files which shall be copied from one location to another. The target location varies, the source location is always the same directory. So I did something like this in my makefile:

```
COPY_FILES += TargetDir1/MySource.c
COPY_FILES += TargetDir2/MyHeader.h

$(COPY_FILES): SourceDir/$(notdir $@)
    @cp $< $@
```

This doesn't work, since the automatic variables are not expanded in prerequisite. But is there a way to achieve the intended behavior? The rules must only be defined for the target files, so I guess % doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a small number of target directories you could use static pattern rules.  If not you'll have to use [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html):

```
COPY_FILES += TargetDir1/MySource.c
COPY_FILES += TargetDir2/MyHeader.h

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(COPY_FILES): SourceDir/$$(@F)
        @cp $< $@
```